# I can't see the MPMoviePlayerControls When Streaming Audio

Tags: audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

I can't see the MPMoviePlayerController controls when I'm streaming only audio, is this normal? All i can see is a black screen, though the audio is playing, however it works when playing video in another view. I hoped this would allow me to use the controls so i didn't have to build my own UI with AVPlayer.

My code is as follow;

```
self.audioPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.audioPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self.audioPlayer setContentURL:self.audioUrl];
[self.audioPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
self.audioPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;


[self.audioPlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:self.audioPlayer.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.audioPlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.audioPlayer];

[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the end i built an AVPlayer with UI rather than use MPmovieplayer.